# Why is dns.resolveMx failing with "gmail.com"

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am trying to debug the [node-sendmail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendmail) package, more specifically I would like to understand the error I am getting when using the `gmail.com` host domain. The error only happens on my Ubuntu 20.04 running under WSL2.

What confuses me is that `resolveMx` works fine on Windows (with gmail) and it is also working on both (wsl Ubuntu and Windows) with other domain, like protonmail.

Running `nslookup` or `dig` also works for the gmail domain on wsl, so it really looks like it's the the syscall used underneath by nodejs which is behaving inconsistently.

In both OSes I am using the same nodejs version: 14.15.4.

The snippet I am using:

```
const dns = require('dns');
const util = require('util');


dns.resolveMx('gmail.com', (err, addresses) => {
  if (err){
    console.log(err); // going here, see error message below
    return;
  }
    console.log(util.inspect(addresses));
});
```

giving the following error, only for the Ubuntu hosted on WSL2:

```
Error: queryMx ETIMEOUT gmail.com
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'queryMx',
  hostname: 'gmail.com'
}
```

On Windows, I got the expected result:

```
[
  { exchange: 'alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', priority: 10 },
  { exchange: 'gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', priority: 5 },
  { exchange: 'alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', priority: 40 },
  { exchange: 'alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', priority: 30 },
  { exchange: 'alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', priority: 20 }
]
```

What confused me even more, is that, if I change gmail for another provider, like protonmail for instance, the mx resolution is working on both wsl distro and Windows.

**Update**

The problem occurs inconsistently, since I got `resolveMx`  working *sometime* on wsl as well.

Comment: Does it always fail in WSL or is it inconsistent? Are you able to `strace` it to see if it's repeatedly looking for nameserver files like /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why yours is failing, but I installed NodeJS 14.15.4 (using n) and ran your snippet with no troubles under WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04.  I received the same results that you did under Windows node, just in a different order.  I'm thinking we need to look at something specific to your environment?

Comment: @ZacAnger It is inconsistent indeed. I did not noticed it because it always failed so far, But after playing with strace, I got it working once. This is confusing me even more...

Comment: I am not familiar with the strace command, should I look for something in particular in the output  ? You mentioned `/etc/resolv.conf`. In the output I indeed have the following entry:

```openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY) = 17
fstat(17, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=198, ...}) = 0
read(17, "# This file was automatically ge"..., 4096) = 198
read(17, "", 4096)                      = 0
close(17)                               = 0
```

Comment: `strace -e open -p (your node process's PID)` is how I would troubleshoot that specific thing. If it was constantly reading from /etc/resolv.conf or a similar file that could point to DNS caching issues, but if there's only one, that's probably not the issue.

Comment: those are the relevant lines I would say:
```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY) = 17
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY) = 17
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY) = 17
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/pts/1", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_CLOEXEC) = 17
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 18
```

Comment: I also manage to save the trace for the case when it works. Diffing the 2 traces does show that the failing case calls `epoll_wait` repeatedly. But understabding what's going on exactly is beyond my skills

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this issue, I had the same issue and was able to solve it by editing the file `/etc/wsl.conf` to add the following:

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

Then edit the file `/etc/resolv.conf` and add my DNS server like so (replace with yours):

```
nameserver 1.2.3.4
```

After a wsl restart (`wsl --shutdown` in Windows command prompt or PS) I didn't encounter the issue again.

Comment: Could you please explain the fix? Like giving a bit of details on why adding the generateResolvConf flag solves the issue.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure as I found this trick elsewhere but it's basically telling wsl to not generate the dns resolving config automatically, and instead you manually specify the dns server to use, which might solve this problem which looks like a dns lookup issue.